# Best home workout that targets the pectoralis minor or the lower chest?

Tags: muscle-gain, chest, home-exercise

I have a good amount of upper chest but lack lower chest, giving my chest a somewhat breast-like appearance. I've gone online to figure out which home exercises I could do that targets mainly the lower chest and all I could get is incline pushup. 
But the thing with that is, it's too easy. Isn't there a harder form of exercise that targets my lower chest so that I can efficiently cause progressive overload OR do I just need to do as many incline pushups as I can handle, increasing it gradually?

Comment: If you find it too easy, do it with a backpack that you filled with heavy stuff (books for instance)

Comment: Since you are unware of dips or the backpack idea or simply doing them pre fatigued, i would get a 2nd opinion on your chest - is it really lacking to the point where you need to target it more or is it just your subjective impression or the natural shape of your pecs - or perhaps something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anatomically speaking you can't  isolate a muscle into parts but the Pectoralis Major  is split into two heads which makes it easier.

[image]

Common myth is that the more you press in an incline  the more upper Pectoralis you use, which is quite the opposite since the upper/clavicular Pectoralis is almost horizontal  and not vertical.

[J Hum Kinet. 2017 Jun](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4gAi.png)

This study  shows that 
Unlike popular belief, vertical movements don't  work the upper chest more, due to it's  position the muscle  is always active. Going from decline/flat to incline only reduces triceps activity while increasing biceps activity.

Boeckh-Behrens & Buskies. 2000 found that decline work (Dips/inverted bench press)
Uses even more upper chest.

[image]

From this chart things like dips or inverted bench press are best for upper chest development  but also best for "lower chest" too.

If you do Dips I suggest sticking with bodyweight  only for safety and to progress just add more repetition every time you train.

Comment: I removed the studies that you edited in from another answer, as they do not do anything to answer the question and are noise.